# R言語で土日祝日を除いた日数の計算結果をデータフレームへ

Tags: r

Rで土日祝日を除いた開始日と終了日の間の日数を計算しようとしましたが、上手くいきません。
ベクトルの型が上手くいかないものと思いますが、何か上手くやる方法はありませんでしょうか。

```
library(dplyr)    
p1 <- c(1:2)
p2 <- as.Date(c("2013-01-01","2013-01-22"))
p3 <- as.Date(c("2013-01-11","2013-01-30"))
df2 <- data_frame(p1,p2,p3)
names(df2) <- c("st_date", "ed_date")

# 政府のcsvより作成：祝日リスト
holidays <- c("1995/1/1",
              "1995/1/2",
              "1995/1/15",
～略~
              "2023/10/9",
              "2023/11/3",
              "2023/11/23"
              )

# https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29838/r%e8%a8%80%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%a7%e5%9c%9f%e6%97%a5%e7%a5%9d%e6%97%a5%e3%82%92%e9%99%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e6%97%a5%e6%95%b0%e3%81%ae%e8%a8%88%e7%ae%97を参考
library(timeDate)
heijitu.f <- function(start, end) {
  hol1995_2023 <- as.Date(unlist(holidays))
  days <- seq.Date(as.Date(start), as.Date(end), by="day")
  result <- length(days[timeDate::isWeekday(days) &! (days %in% hol1995_2023)])
  return(result)
}

df2 <- df2 %>% dplyr::mutate(heijitu.f(st_date, ed_date))
# ここでエラー：'from' must be of length 1
```

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Calculate seconds between 2 timestamps in R excluding weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56262872/9014308), [Difference between two dates excluding weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23028384/9014308), [Difference between two dates excluding weekends and given list of holidays in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37068210/9014308) また最近のPythonでの類似質問。[土日を無いものとしてdatetimeに加算をしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/88361/26370)

Comment: Pythonのパッケージと同じ名前のものがあったので、同様に使えるかもしれません。[BusinessDuration: Calculates Business Duration Between Two Dates](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BusinessDuration/index.html) あとは探すと類似のものが。[bizdays: Business Days Calculations and Utilities](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bizdays/index.html), [fmdates: Financial Market Date Calculations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fmdates/index.html), [bdscale: Remove Weekends and Holidays from ggplot2 Axes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bdscale/index.html) あるいはソースコードを基に必要な機能を自分で追加するとか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)    

p1 <- c(1:2)
p2 <- as.Date(c("2013-01-01","2013-01-22"))
p3 <- as.Date(c("2013-01-11","2013-01-30"))
df2 <- data_frame(p1,p2,p3)
names(df2) <- c("no", "st_date", "ed_date")

# 政府のcsvより作成：祝日リスト
holidays <- c("1995/1/1",
              "1995/1/2",
              "1995/1/15",
～略~
              "2023/10/9",
              "2023/11/3",
              "2023/11/23"
              )

library(timeDate)
heijitu.f <- function(start, end) {
  hol1995_2023 <- as.Date(unlist(holidays))
  days <- seq.Date(as.Date(start), as.Date(end), by="day")
  result <- length(days[timeDate::isWeekday(days) &! (days %in% hol1995_2023)])
  return(result)
}

df2 <- df2 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(days = heijitu.f(st_date, ed_date))

print(df2)

#
     no st_date    ed_date     days
  <int> <date>     <date>     <int>
1     1 2013-01-01 2013-01-11     8
2     2 2013-01-22 2013-01-30     7
```